# Sort an Array using C++ in R

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I need to arrange a dataframe of prices, row by row in ascedent order.
But doing it on R for Loop is quite bad and slow.

A friend of mine tipped me to use Rcpp.
But I'm having quite a hard time to develop a looping in C++ that works.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]

using namespace std;
                  
List min(NumericVector x) 
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {
        vector<int>& vec = x[i];
        NumericVector Value sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
        }
Return Value;

    }
```

I'm not used to C++ and i would like to know why it keeps saying that mys sort is wrong.

Arrange my dataframe by row.

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to sort _rows_ from left to right by ascending value, or columns by ascending value? Or sort a data frame according to the values in a single  column? Your question isn't very clear. Could you perhaps give a very small example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome (again) to StackOverflow and Rcpp! Two big worlds with much to discover...

`sort()` is available as a member function:

```r
> Rcpp::cppFunction("NumericVector srt(NumericVector x) { return(x.sort()); }")
> srt(c(2,3,4,1.5,3.2))
[1] 1.5 2.0 3.0 3.2 4.0
>
```

Note that an advanced question is hidden inside this simple because the `sort()` member function *sorts in place* so the above mutates its input.  That can be convenient ("hey, no new heap object to return") or confusing depending on your vantage point.  We cover it in most Rcpp tutorials but you may have other more pressing issue.  Keep on it!

Comment: The OP seems to want to sort a data frame, and I'm guessing that this is an x / y question to which the real answer will lie in `data.table`.

Comment: Spot on Allan. My immediate reflex also was _but sorting a vector is already as fast as it gets_.  But them young ones think they get lightspeed just by sampling the letters 'R', 'c', 'p' with replications. _If only it was so easy_ ...  So my answer mostly tried to address the 'half-STL, half-Rcpp' usage error in the above.

Comment: I actually already do thata in R. But as I have a million rows to loop, this task becomes slow. That's why I've tried to migrate to Rcpp

Comment: @danielsouza take a look at `data.table::setorder()` - it will do what you want without you having to reinvent what it's already doing.

Comment: @SymbolixAU thanks fot the tip! I will try it out!